# ROS2 installation error: File has unexpected size

Tags: ros2, installation

System Ubuntu22.04, in a new virtual machine.

When installing ros2, I run

```
sudo apt update
```

and get error

```
Hit:1 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Hit:3 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Get:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease [4,682 B]
Get:6 http://166.111.9.4:8081/IXCc1e1557fd34181d1a08c6412c867075c_183.172.194.16/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1,304 kB]
Err:6 http://166.111.9.4:8081/IXCc1e1557fd34181d1a08c6412c867075c_183.172.194.16/ros2/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (1259667 != 1303955). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 166.111.9.4 8081]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:1303955 [weak]
   - SHA256:f08835aa88f675a2b37def7186788f93b1ce3e404acafe8209cdc2a8fb5e94e9
   - SHA1:307d5be1bf3a2e130e66f0e49ee9f2dc8b30c447 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:70e1487590668979fbe9c4642484b171 [weak]
  Release file created at: Fri, 11 Aug 2023 02:39:29 +0000
Fetched 4,682 B in 2s (2,568 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://166.111.9.4:8081/IXCc1e1557fd34181d1a08c6412c867075c_183.172.194.16/ros2/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  File has unexpected size (1259667 != 1303955). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 166.111.9.4 8081]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:1303955 [weak]
    - SHA256:f08835aa88f675a2b37def7186788f93b1ce3e404acafe8209cdc2a8fb5e94e9
    - SHA1:307d5be1bf3a2e130e66f0e49ee9f2dc8b30c447 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:70e1487590668979fbe9c4642484b171 [weak]
   Release file created at: Fri, 11 Aug 2023 02:39:29 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The mirror you're using probably synced the files (or has server problem) while you were trying to update, see the `File has unexpected size (...). Mirror sync in progress?` message.
Just try `apt-get clean` and then `apt-get update` again. If the error still occurs, you should switch to another mirror as your currently used mirror seems to be faulty. Therefore you should remove the `166.111.9.4` entry from your sources located somewhere in `/etc/apt/`.

Comment: Agree that the use of the mirror is likely the issue here.  Either updating the mirror or using the upstream should fix it.